# How CSS file upload to index.html file in Github?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, tags

I uploaded index.html and CSS file in githuib pages.

like the images I uploaded.

But I don't know for what reason the CSS didn't load into index.html.

I guess it is because of the problem of the link addresse, but I don't how to fix it.

To make the CSS file to index.html file, how do i fix my codes?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNNdq.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

you probably do have some problem with the linking of the css file.

normally css file should be linked between the head tag like this:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet "href="filename.css">
</head>
```

to extend on this, if you have deployed your website on github pages, to see the effects there you need to push your changes to github first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried to fix my problem as you said and finally, it got working now.

Answer (score 0):

i want to add to Liemannen loop answer,

sometimes we need to add "./" on the css link like this if for some reason the css is not loaded

< link rel="stylesheet" href="./stylesheet.css">

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I will try it as you said.